# Animating a QRect with QPropertyAnimation

Tags: qt, animation, qrect

I have a bunch of QRects and some text in a QGraphicsScene that I am trying to animate with QPropertyAnimation. Animating the text works fine but the QRects don't work because they fail to convert to a QGraphicsObject

This works perfectly

```
QPropertyAnimation *a = new QPropertyAnimation(this);
a->setTargetObject(items[size.x()*size.y()-1-aa]->toGraphicsObject()); //text
a->setPropertyName("pos");
a->setDuration(animationLength);
a->setStartValue(items[size.x()*size.y()-1-aa]->pos());
a->setEndValue(newTextPos);
a->setEasingCurve(easingCurve);
a->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
```

But this doesn't, because items[2*size.x()*size.y()-2-aa]->toGraphicsObject() returns a null pointer.

```
QPropertyAnimation *a = new QPropertyAnimation(this);
a->setTargetObject(items[2*size.x()*size.y()-2-aa]->toGraphicsObject()); //rect
a->setPropertyName("pos");
a->setDuration(animationLength);
a->setStartValue(items[2*size.x()*size.y()-2-aa]->pos());
a->setEndValue(newRectPos);
a->setEasingCurve(easingCurve);
a->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: QRect is not a graphics item, do you mean QGraphicsRectItem?

Comment: uh, maybe. I added the rects with QGraphicsScene::addRect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toGraphicsObject` returns null pointer because `QGraphicsRectItem` is not a `QGraphicsObject`. You cannot use `QGraphicsRectItem` to perform an animation. I can suggest two workarounds:

1. Create your own class derived from `QObject` and `QGraphicsRectItem`, create "pos" property and implement its getter and setter.
2. Create your own class derived from `QGraphicsObject`. Implement its `boundingRect` and `paint` pure virtual methods to make it paint a rectangle.